# Maven: How to handle local files on sub projects for tests

Tags: java, testing, testng, maven-3

I have a Maven project with sub projects. I added a test to one of the sub projects which uses a file from it's test resources and works fine using:

```
new File("target/coverage/report");
```

It works fine but when running the tests from the parent project it fails failing to find some files. I assume it's looking at the root of the parent folder instead.

Is there a way to handle this so it works on both scenarios?

Comment: I guess you could duplicate the files, but that beats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You may specify them using the "resources/resource*     List" as described in the following document.

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-model/maven.html#class_build

Comment: That seems to be classpath related. Not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at the Remote Resources Plugin, as presented in this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/examples/sharing-resources.html).
This plugin allows you to group your shared resources in a separate module, which will be then bundled into a JAR file that can be consumed from any lifecycle phase by other modules.